# $C^{\infty}_{loc}$-convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be some open set. Let $f_{n},f\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. My question is: What does the following phrase mean? $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $C^{\infty}_{loc}(\Omega)$. What is the exact definition of such a convergence.

Comment: I'm not sure, but usually in $L^1_{loc}$ I would understand convergence to be convergence wrt the seminorms $|f|_K = \int_K |f|$ where $K$ is a compacta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probably means that restricted to any compact subset $K\subset \Omega $, you have convergence $ f_n\to f $ in each $ C^m $ norm.

Comment: don' you need to extract subsequences? I am not sure if the following is correct. For each compact $K \subset \Omega$ and each integer $m\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ there exists a subsequence of the sequence $(f_{n})$ which converges to $f$ in $C^{m}(K)$.

Comment: Is this definition correct ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to extract subsequences? If the author doesn't mention it I don't think he means it

Comment: Actually what I am trying to prove is the following: Let $f_{n} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that there exists a constant $C>0$ with $||f_{n}||_{C^{0}(\mathbb{R})} < C$ and $||f'_{n}||_{C^{0}(\mathbb{R})} < C$. Furthermore, we assume that for each $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ compact and each $k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ there exists a constant $C_{K,k}$ suhc that $||f^{(k)}_{n}||_{C^{0}(K)} < C_{K,k}$. Show: There exists a function $g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f_{n}\rightarrow g$ in $C^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You can indeed only show this for a sub sequence. The author must have forgotten to mention that