# $C^{\infty}_{loc}$ convergence vs $C^{\infty}$ convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading the definition of $C^{\infty}_{loc}$ convergence from [$C^{\infty}_{loc}$-convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668835/c-infty-loc-convergence). Is quite confusing since if we define it as in the post, then what should be the definition of $C^{\infty}$ convergence?

Answer (score 0):

$f_n$ converge to $f$ in $C^\infty(X)$ if they converge in each $C^\infty(X)$-norm.

$C^\infty_{loc}(X)$ only concerns functions' behaviour in every compact subset $K\subset X$, i.e., the functions are convergent in $C^\infty(K)$ for each compact $K\subset X$, rather than a global bahaviour, while for convergence in $C^\infty(X)$, you need to consider convergence in the whole space $X$.

For example, $f_n(x)=e^{nx}$ converge to $0$ in $C^\infty_{loc}(-\infty,0)$ but do not converge in $C^\infty(-\infty,0)$.